# How to retrieve current Windows user login using C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm new to C. How can i retrieve the current user logged into Windows using C?

I know you can do this in C++ by Environment::UserName, but have no idea how to do it in C.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you need just the name or other details of the user?

Comment: Do you mean the user who is running your code?  There can be more than one user logged in at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`GetUserName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724432%28VS.85%29.aspx):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>

TCHAR username[UNLEN+1];
DWORD len = UNLEN+1;
if (GetUserName(username, &len))
{
    //do something with username
}
```